# Graph Api PHP Photo Upload from App endpoint/response problem

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, photo, endpoint

Using Facebook's Graph API, I'm uploading a photo from my iFrame app via a form:

```
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
.$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
echo '<input name="message" 
  type="text" value=""><br/><br/>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
echo '</form>';
```

$graph_url is defined before this form like this:

```
$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
    . "access_token=" .$access_token;
```

This is working and I can upload photos with my app to the users profile, however, once the photo is uploaded the contents of my iFrame is replaced with a 'response' from the graph:

example:

```
  {
   "id": "1001207389476"
  }
```

I want to avoid this being displayed and instead show a success screen perhaps showing a link to the newely uploaded image also.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I've been pulling my hair out for the last three days just trying to do this!

For reference here are the tutorials from where I got my code:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ and http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

one solution I can think is you can use a try catch block to catch the photo uploading code. If no exception happens, and you do get the uploaded pic id. You can print "photo upload succeed" instead of showing the pic id.

To get the link of the pic. You do need to use your pic id. You can try 
graph.facebook.com/your-pic-id  (Probably with some access_token) and inside it, you can get the link of this picture.

see the graph API for photos:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm trying to give this ago, but I'm not sure how tgo use catch. I'll keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a redirect uri in your $graph_url? Don't know the exact name of the parameter Facebook is expecting but I think it's redirect_uri.

Edit_: To make ist more clear, Facebook will look for that parameter in the Graph URL and redirect to that URI if your request is completed. So you could define http://yourdomain.com/yourapp/upload_finished.php. I'm not 100% sure if they will also pass the ID of the uploaded photo to this URI but that should be the case.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you reply. I have tried this and it seems like the redirect link doesn't work for this. I'm not too hot at PHP, so there could be something in the Thinkdiff code I have used that is causing my problem, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 0):

Add onsubmit attribute to form tag: 
And you can do everything with JavaScript, for example show message or success screen.

Comment: < form … onsubmit="function_to_be_run_when_a_form_is_submitted" >

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I have given it a quick try, but it looks like I would have to also submit the form through javascript and stop the defaultsubmit action otherwise I still get the same problem after the function has been carried out. Does that sound right?

Comment: May be use of submit button relocate you? Try standart button, and call form submit in Javascript. http://w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp